# SD card mounted as bootable image instead of FAT 32

Tags: macos, usb, photos, usb-flash-drive, sd-card

I have an SD card that I recently used to take photos on vacation. It have taken a lot of photos using it and worked fine on the camera.

However, I had forgotten that a few months before this trip, I tried to make the SD card a bootable Xubuntu USB drive.

So when I plugged my SD card in to copy the photos, the card mounts as the Xubuntu image, rather than mounting as the FAT32 drive with the images on it.

The files must still be on the drive. Any ideas on how to fix this? (I'm using Mac OS X) Thanks!

Comment: What make you think "the files must still be on the drive"?  It sounds to me like the Ubuntu image creator probably wrote over the top of them. Most of the bootable-image programs I'm familiar with assume you're giving them free reign to overwrite the SD.

Answer (score 1):

Generally cameras tend to store photos in a folder called DCIM. See if its there, and the photos are in a subfolder of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using Mac's Disk Utility and see if there are additional partitions. If all you can see is your Xubuntu image partition, I'm not sure there's much you can do.

Can you still see the images directly on the cam?
If you go to a Windows machine, can you see another partition?
If you go to a Linux machine, can you see another partition? (I hope you can find a Linux machine. If not, try burning a live CD and booting off of that.)